# What is "Virtual()" function in PHP?

Tags: php

Can anyone explain me what is use of "Virtual()" function of PHP? I am not able to get its meaning.

**Resource:**
http://php.net/manual/en/function.virtual.php

Comment: This would help you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898383/sending-files-by-apache-and-php-virtual-function-with-http-range-support

Comment: Giving a +1 for counteracting the negative vote given. OP is right, in the documentation the definition of virtual function given is very ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Server Side Includes are [explained in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes).

An `include virtual` statement takes a path relative to your www root directory, flushes all current output and streams the virtual's output just like i.e. `fpassthru()`.